# How to implement kiosk application in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to implement kiosk application in WPF. I have a terminal. Terminal has card reader and laser printer. I learned print on laser print, and learned to identify card by card reader.

I ask Google many times, and no results. 
Could you give me any links, or any hints in implementing this application.

Application will have buttons, images, and animation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Just run your application as fulls-creen and [replace the default Windows Shell with it](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/228309).

For it, you need to replace the `explorer.exe` (Windows Explorer, which loads the desktop, start bar, startmenu etc.) with your own app. Then you get the same result as your application running and shutting down `explorer.exe` from Task Manager.

The registry key in question is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon\Shell`.

The only challenge remaining is to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> combination, but that's a separate question.

Comment: My application will be desktop application, yes i learned to disable hot combinations.

Comment: Yea, but you still have to make it run in fullscreen. Because you have to disable the internet explorer and there isn't anything else there anymore. So no point in run it in a small window, cause user can't do anything else besides interacting with the application

Comment: also you need to run your form in topmost form. one more thing you can do is create a window service which will run in background and check if you application is running if not just restart your application.