# Start .Net Application After Logging in

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, authentication

I need to create an .Net application which is automatically start after windows logging in. on that time i dont want to show our desktop and windows related things.

Is it possible?I need to create one more layer between login and our Windows.That layer is our .Net Application

Comment: Would be helpful to know the version of Windows you are using. For example, Windows 8.1 has a "kiosk" mode that allows you to do this. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get it. It is either a [Windows Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx), which is an application that runs in the background all the time, or some kind of a [Kiosk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29470432/how-to-implement-kiosk-application-in-wpf) application, which sits "on top" of everything and is effectively the only UI to the PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can start make a Schedule Task and run it

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

p.s you can only can run cmd files